# How to change or replace database sqlite inside Iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

I have a problem with the sqlite database. In my app i read an external db that I copy inside the iphone. It works!! Now I modified the database and I Have to replace it inside the iphone. I deleted the database from project and i put the new one (same name), then I start the simulator (or the iphone) and the app use again the old database. 
This is the code i use for copy the database:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *appDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"On4h.db"];
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"On4h.db"];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appDBPath];
if (success) {
    return;
}

success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:appDBPath error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

How it's possible to replace the database with another with the same name? How its possible that now the iphone read again the old one?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the database you need to do the below..

1. Open Preferences

   [image]
2. Go to location Tab and click on the arrow indicating.

[image]

3. Now go through the following :

`Application Support -> iPhone Simulator -> 7.1 (your simulator version) -> Applications -> Find out your project -> Library -> Caches`

on the above location you will found your old database. Now replace it with new one.

[image]

**NOTE:** Above process is for the `iPhone/iPad simulator only`. For iPhone/ iPad devices you need to delete and reinstall the app.